# Addition of elements in multiple list corresponding to a key column of RDD

Tags: pyspark

I have PythonRDDs. I have to perform addition of elements for multiple lists. Add element 1 of list 1 to element 1 of list 2 then add to element 1 of list 3.
For Canada, add 47,59,77 as element 1, 97,98,63 as second element and so on.

I tried to flatten the list to add them and tried to convert to dataframe but I failed to do so. And I want to do it through all 3 ways

```
countryCounts = [
('CANADA','47;97;33;94;6'),
('CANADA','59;98;24;83;3'),
('CANADA','77;63;93;86;62'),
('CHINA','86;71;72;23;27'),
('CHINA','74;69;72;93;7'),
('CHINA','58;99;90;93;41'),
('ENGLAND','40;13;85;75;90'),
('ENGLAND','39;13;33;29;14'),
('ENGLAND','99;88;57;69;49'),
('GERMANY','67;93;90;57;3'),
('GERMANY','9;15;20;19'),
('GERMANY','77;64;46;95;48'),
('INDIA','90;49;91;14;70'),
('INDIA','70;83;38;27;16'),
('INDIA','86;21;19;59;4')
]
countryCountsRdd = sc.parallelize(countryCounts)
countryCountsSplit.collect()
countryCountsGroup=countryCountsSplit.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
countryCountsGroup.collect()
CountsSplit=countryCountsRdd.map(lambda x : (x[0], ",".join(x[1].split(';'))))
countryCountsSplit.collect()

Inputs :
Way 1
[('CANADA', [47, 97, 33, 94, 6]), ('CANADA', [59, 98, 24, 83, 3]), ('CANADA', [77, 63, 93, 86, 62]), ('CHINA', [86, 71, 72, 23, 27]), ('CHINA', [74, 69, 72, 93, 7]), ('CHINA', [58, 99, 90, 93, 41]), ('ENGLAND', [40, 13, 85, 75, 90]), ('ENGLAND', [39, 13, 33, 29, 14]), ('ENGLAND', [99, 88, 57, 69, 49]), ('GERMANY', [67, 93, 90, 57, 3]), ('GERMANY', [9, 15, 20, 19]), ('GERMANY', [77, 64, 46, 95, 48]), ('INDIA', [90, 49, 91, 14, 70]), ('INDIA', [70, 83, 38, 27, 16]), ('INDIA', [86, 21, 19, 59, 4])] 
Way 2:
[('CANADA', [[47, 97, 33, 94, 6], [59, 98, 24, 83, 3], [77, 63, 93, 86, 62]]), ('CHINA', [[86, 71, 72, 23, 27], [74, 69, 72, 93, 7], [58, 99, 90, 93, 41]]), ('INDIA', [[90, 49, 91, 14, 70], [70, 83, 38, 27, 16], [86, 21, 19, 59, 4]]), ('ENGLAND', [[40, 13, 85, 75, 90], [39, 13, 33, 29, 14], [99, 88, 57, 69, 49]]), ('GERMANY', [[67, 93, 90, 57, 3], [9, 15, 20, 19], [77, 64, 46, 95, 48]])]
Way 3:
[('CANADA', '47 ,97 ,33 ,94 ,6'), ('CANADA', '59 ,98 ,24 ,83 ,3'), ('CANADA', '77 ,63 ,93 ,86 ,62'), ('CHINA', '86 ,71 ,72 ,23 ,27'), ('CHINA', '74 ,69 ,72 ,93 ,7'), ('CHINA', '58 ,99 ,90 ,93 ,41'), ('ENGLAND', '40 ,13 ,85 ,75 ,90'), ('ENGLAND', '39 ,13 ,33 ,29 ,14'), ('ENGLAND', '99 ,88 ,57 ,69 ,49'), ('GERMANY', '67 ,93 ,90 ,57 ,3'), ('GERMANY', '9 ,15 ,20 ,19'), ('GERMANY', '77 ,64 ,46 ,95 ,48'), ('INDIA', '90 ,49 ,91 ,14 ,70'), ('INDIA', '70 ,83 ,38 ,27 ,16'), ('INDIA', '86 ,21 ,19 ,59 ,4')]

Require same output for all 3 : 
[('CANADA','183;258;150;263;71)]
[('CHINA','218,239,234,209,75')]
[('ENGLAND','178,114,175,173,153')]
[('GERMANY','144,166,151,172,70')]
[('INDIA','246,153,148,100,90')]
```

Comment: I tried group by "countryCountsGroup" but it created nested list which I am not able to sum up.

Comment: Your output for Germany looks incorrect. It seems like one of your entries has only 4 elements.

Comment: Yes Pault. You are right. Output for Germany is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine the values for a given key by taking the sum. This is precisely what `reduceByKey` does. You just need to define an associative and commutative reduce function to combine the values as desired.

```python
def myReducer(a, b):
    a, b = map(int, a.split(";")), map(int, b.split(";"))
    maxLength = max(len(a), len(b))
    if len(a) < len(b):
        a = a + [0]*(len(b)-len(a))
    elif len(b) < len(a):
        b = b + [0]*(len(a)-len(b))
    return ";".join([str(a[i] + b[i]) for i in range(maxLength)])
```

The only real tricky part here is that your sample input lists are not all the same size. In this case, I defined the function to zero pad the shorter list.

Now call `reduceByKey`:

```python
countryCountsRdd.reduceByKey(myReducer).collect()
#[('CANADA', '183;258;150;263;71'),
# ('CHINA', '218;239;234;209;75'),
# ('INDIA', '246;153;148;100;90'),
# ('ENGLAND', '178;114;175;173;153'),
# ('GERMANY', '153;172;156;171;51')]
```

Comment: Thanks Pault. If data is incorrect then the logic will correct by replacing NULL with 0.

Comment: Pault could you please share the code for myCombiner. Because when I am using countryCountsReduceByKey=countryCountsSplit.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y), it is giving me [('CANADA', [47, 97, 33, 94, 6, 59, 98, 24, 83, 3, 77, 63, 93, 86, 62])] which is concatenation that is not expected.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh `myCombiner` was a typo- it should have been `myReducer` (fixed). You apply it on `countryCountsRdd`, NOT `countCountsSplit`. Why are you trying your own function? `x+y` for lists will concatenate lists.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do it using a simple reduceByKey operation on RDD.

INPUT RDD - RDD[STRING, LIST]

Output RDD - input.reduceByKey(x,y -> addFunction(x,y))

addFunction (x,y) iterates over the input lists and add the elements index wise and returns the added list